# Linq to SQL creating duplicate designer files

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have a strange bug with my Linq to SQL DBML files, when ever I save it, instead of saving to the existing designer file a duplicate file is created.

This is causing errors all over the place as there is ambiguity between the data context constructor inside of file.designer.cs and file1.designer.cs

Is there any way to fix this error that doesnt involve deleting and recreating the dmbl files. as this error is happening on all of my DBML files some of which are rather large.

[image]

The above image shows the issue that I'm having.

Comment: I wonder... is this perhaps VCS related? is that file perhaps readonly?

Comment: Just checked and the file is not read only. Deleting both of the designer files and rebuilding the dbml leaves me with just 1 designer file and it works but it is still minerva1.designer.cs can't seem to remove the "1"

Comment: intriguing; if you do a find-in-files for "Minerva1", maybe something will appear? (maybe it is explicit in the dbml, for example)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Not sure what could have caused this (but Marc's suggestion about the file being readonly or not checked out seems possible), but the association is described in the .proj file. If you open that file with a text editor you should see somewhere within something like:

```
<ItemGroup>
<None Include="Minerva.dbml">
  <Generator>MSLinqToSQLGenerator</Generator>
  <LastGenOutput>Minerva1.designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
  <SubType>Designer</SubType>
</None>
```

Replace `Minerva1.designer.cs` with `Minerva.designer.cs`. You can now delete or exclude the `Minerva1.designer.cs` file from you project and the next time the generator is invoked it will overwrite `Minerva.designer.cs` as expected.

Comment: I was experiencing the same problem when I added DB model in ANOTHER project as LINK, I solved the problem like you said in the second project's .proj file. Thank you :)

Comment: This was my problem also.  It happened right after I connected to a different instance of the database associated with the designer, then dragged some new tables onto the designer and saved.  Changing the .proj file fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. It turns out version control was holding the file. The build process cannot recreate the file so it creates a new one. Since this file is automatically generated, it is safe to remove from the version control. I am using git for my version control.

Comment: Grrrr... you were absolutely right.  Sometimes VS2013 will check-out the .dbml file, but not the designer.cs file... then will create extra designer.cs files.   Thanks for the tip !