# Saving dbml file creates a new designer.cs file

Tags: linq-to-sql

Every time I save my dbml file after updating or adding new database objects, a new designer.cs file is created and the old designer remains unchanged. I believe the dbml is corrupted but am unsure about the resolution. Google doesn't seem to be particularly helpful either. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Klaas, have you been able to find the solution to this behaviour? Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linq to SQL creating duplicate designer files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7820020/linq-to-sql-creating-duplicate-designer-files)

Comment: @itisinteresting, I am still dumbfounded as to why that happened. It worked alright after I restarted Visual Studio. (I am working on VS 2010)

Comment: I get a new designer file added when I add a function to the dbml using the designer gui.  The new filename is oldfilename1.designer.cs

Comment: anyone found a solution for this? I have the same issue.

Answer (score -1):

At first it sounds perfectly normal that a new code file is generated every time you change something on the model.

But because you say '*the old designer remains unchanged*' I assume the new designer.cs file has some extension in its file name to distinguish it from the old one. You can't have two files with the same name in one directory.
Have you checked that the old designer file isn't read-only? Maybe due some file-versioning system you have used.

In the perfect world I would think you get an error message in this kind of situations, but with computers you never know.